# What are the conformal Ward identities associated with the correlation functions of the stress-energy tensor?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions, ward-identity

I found two papers on this matter, but am having trouble parsing the answer from either of them.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05359

https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.06767

For that matter, what even are the correlation functions for the stress-energy tensor?

I would very much appreciate the answer being phrased in as simple of a fashion as possible and for a source to be provided for reference purposes.

Comment: Ward identities are constraints which only sometimes determine correlation functions. It's backwards to say you don't even know the harder of those two things.

Comment: My understanding is that CWIs arise due to invariance of correlation functions under conformal transformations. You're saying that, in the reverse, it's also possible to (sometimes) find the correlation functions if given the CWIs? To be clear, I'm saying I don't know either of these things and am seeking clarification on both.

Comment: Have you tried the yellow book (Di Francesco)?

Comment: I have not. I'm trying to learn the fundamentals from Lancaster & Blundell before moving on to a more advanced text, but I'm also trying to prepare a research proposal for a doctoral program at the same time, which is why I'm approaching more advanced concepts.

Comment: Honestly, there's no reason at all to avoid the yellow book. It is very pedagogic IMO. You should try it because it has a very clear description of the Ward identities. Let me also suggest the lecture notes by David Simons-Duffin on the bootstrap and by Hugh Osborn on CFT.

Comment: I'll check it out. I'm just hesitant to jump at new books since my budget is a bit tight right now.